# How to fade out neighbors of a hovered link?

Tags: jquery, navigation, hover

i'm very sorry if I ask this not for the first time...

I wish that if I hover an a-element, that the neighbors of it becomes gray or fade out a little bit. 
Here is my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/chaosman/68797by9/)

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="">Start</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Produktion</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Galerie</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Support</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Kontakt</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Bestellen</a></li>
</ul>

$("#nav > li > a").hover(function(){
    $(this).parent().nextAll("li").css("color", "gray");
});
```

Im very thankful if u can help me (and sorry for the bad english)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can toggle a class on the links that are not hovered using `.toggleClass()`.

```
$("#nav > li > a").hover(function(){
  $('#nav > li > a').not(this).toggleClass('toggle');
});
```

Here is a working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Reedpm2/68797by9/4/) for reference

Comment: good one :), but targeting All `a` links isn't good, so make it to `$("#nav > li > a")`

Comment: Exactly what i was trying to do!! Thanks a lot (: You made one guy in germany happy!

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#nav > li > a").hover(function(){
  $(this).css("color", "green").parent().siblings().find("a").css("color", "gray");
});
```

I believe you expect, to change the color of other `li>a` when hovered, so use of `siblings()` will play the trick.

Working Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/68797by9/1/

Comment: Yes that expression I was searching for. Thank you! The next problem will be, that it stays gray, also if i leave the hover-state. And it shouldn't do.

Comment: Hey @user5857398, you can refer Hoopson2's answer, that is better than mine. :)